# How can export list of Cloud Messaging topics using Postman (or any client)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I want to get a list of all Cloud Messaging topics that have been created by my app. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) shows that I need to fire a GET request to the `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN` endpoint with an Authorization header containing my API key. For example:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA?details=true
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

**Steps**:

1. Get `IID_TOKEN` by printing `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()` in my
   iOS app. This returns a 152 character long string.
2. Get Authorization key from `API_KEY` in `GoogleService-Info.plist`. This is a 39 character long string.
3. Fire GET request using [Postman Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

[image]

**Result**:

I get `MissingAuthorization`. Either I am providing the wrong `IID_TOKEN`, `API_KEY` (unlikely), or setting authorization header incorrectly in Postman.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When setting `Authorization` in Postman, are you adding a prefix of `key=` to the value of the API key? (e.g. `key=abcdefg:hijkl23456`)

Comment: I see an upvote in my comment, but I'm not sure if it's yours @Jon. Did it work? Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @AL. Yes, tried `key=` as a prefix to the API_KEY. Also tried to use `Authorization:key` as the header key but Postman said it was invalid, which makes sense.

Comment: This is strange. Could you try [sending a request through cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26480/sending-downstream-messages-via-curl#t=201706130757081460972) and see if it shows the same response?

Comment: It is odd. I thought adding `key=` as you suggested would fix it as well. I tried sending a request using PHP's cURL library and didn't get any further. I'll try sending some other types of requests, such as the one you linked, to see if I can get anything working. Resolving this issue is pretty low priority for me. I should be able to figure this out on my own now. Will post back once I have more time to mess around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server key directly from Firebase -> Project settings -> Cloud Messagings:
[image]

After that, you can create a request using Postman in this way:
[image]

Or you can use Authorizations OAuth 2.0 in this way:
[image]